# What does ^L refer to in vi?

Tags: vi

This is probably a simple question, I know it isn't a carriage return so I expect it is a line/page break but can someone confirm what `^L` refers to in Vi.

Essentially I have a file which contains a lot of letters;  I can see the `^L` at the start of the lines which break the file up into each individual letter and I would like to use this to edit the file so I can move the Name/address lines a few centimetres to fit the envelopes.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_Feed#Form_feed

Comment: [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) is a quick source of general info on control characters.

Comment: it's not a `vi` thing, it's an `ASCII` thing, from the days of line printers.

Comment: [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table) this is the ref. I was looking for

Comment: Thanks, apologies for confusing it.any advice as to how to use it to edit the file? I tried see but it didn't work (new to some of this... All of this)

Comment: Use what? ^L? You can't. Vi? Google "vi" tutorial.